# Ошибка Corresponding method handler '`public void setOnClickListener(android.view.View)`' not found

Tags: android, kotlin

Kotlin
Пытаюсь привязать функцию **setOnClickListener**  к кнопке через onClick

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            val projectDirAbsolutePath = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString()
            val resourcesPath = Paths.get(projectDirAbsolutePath, "/0/storage/emulated/tmp")
            val paths = Files.walk(resourcesPath)
                .forEach { item -> FileWriter("/0/storage/emulated/jjj.txt").use { it.write("$item") } }
        }
    }
}
```

. Но в одной и той же строчке активности XML

```
android:onClick="setOnClickListener"
```

я получаю ошибку *Corresponding method handler '`public void setOnClickListener(android.view.View)`' not found* и предупреждение *Method 'setOnClickListener' is missing in 'MainActivity' or has incorrect signature*. Насколько я понял, проблема в **android.view.View**, но я прописал `import android.view.View`. Пишет, что не используется. И всё равно ошибка остаётся. Приложение компилируется, но при нажатии на собственно кнопку вылетает. Как решить?

Comment: Во-первых, незачем вешать обработчик и в коде и в разметке. Как правило что-то одно. Во-вторых у вас нет публичного метода `setOnClickListener`, чтобы подключить его в разметке, ошибка вам об этом явно говорит.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja спасибо, понял ошибку. И правда банальная... А как сделать метод публичным? Везде написано, что, если не указано обратное, он и так публичный, тут ничего не указано

Comment: Так у вас и метода-то нет никакого, читайте сообщение об ошибке внимательно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Метод не находится, хотя он публичный (Kotlin)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1339007/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-kotlin)