# Метод не находится, хотя он публичный (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

В Kotlin, насколько я понимаю (только учусь), если не указано обратное, метод публичен. У меня метод `setOnClickListener` никаких подробностей не имеет, но, тем не менее, XML при попытке привязать его к кнопке найти его не может:

> Corresponding method handler '`public void setOnClickListener(android.view.View)`' not found

Как сделать setOnClickListener видимым? Код ниже

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            val projectDirAbsolutePath = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString()
            val resourcesPath = Paths.get(projectDirAbsolutePath, "/0/storage/emulated/tmp")
            val paths = Files.walk(resourcesPath)
                .forEach { item -> FileWriter("/0/storage/emulated/jjj.txt").use { it.write("$item") } }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: setOnClickListener() назначает слушатель кликов объекту виджета. Его не надо указывать в XML разметке, при таком указании слушателя, он будет назначен объекту автоматически. Вы можете просто создать ЛЮБОЙ собственный метод в активити с действиями при клике и указать его в разметке, как обработчик кликов.

Comment: Вы получаете ошибку "metod not found", потому что через XML можно назначить на обработку кликов только метод, который реализован в активити, а setOnClickListener не метод активити (а виджетов) и вы получаете ошибку, что он не найден, а не потому, что он не публичный.

Comment: Вы забыли привести самую информативную часть сообщения об ошибке: `Method 'setOnClickListener' is missing in 'MainActivity' or has incorrect signature`. У вас нет метода `setOnClickListener`, его надо написать самому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методы да, по умолчанию публичные. Но вы путаете объявление своего метода с вызовом уже имеющегося, куда вы передаёте экземпляр аномимного класса в виде лямбды.

Если опустить то, что указывать метод клика через разметку не стоит (если вы не используете data-binding) вам надо объявить в классе активити новый метод и на него ссылаться в разметке. Что, опять таки, может быть излишним, т.к. у вас в коде слушатель клика и так уже повешен на кнопку программно. Т.е. можно просто из разметки удалить его и всё будет работать.